# Set max rows for collections

Tags: api-platform.com

Is it possible to define a maximum number of rows for collections attached to an API Platform entity?

E.g.

```
class Contact
```

{

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Reminder", mappedBy="contacts")
 * @Groups({"contact"})
 * @ApiProperty(readable=true,
 *              attributes={"swagger_context"={
 *              "description": "List of reminders"
 *              ... LIMIT NUMBER OF reminders by Contact (e.g. : returns the first 10 reminders)
 * }})
 */
private $reminders;
```

Thanks

Comment: is this for pagination?

Comment: Yes. I want to recover some of the child elements at the same time as the entity. Then later in the app retrieve the following items if needed.
The goal is to avoid unnecessary overfetching.

Comment: I tested the pagination with the element "maximum_items_per_page" directly on the entity "Reminder" but it does not limit the number of items retrieved

Comment: Hello, Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: E.g. : add annotation for that ? :
 `* subresourceOperations={
 *              "maximum_items_per_page"=10
 *     }`

Comment: Easiest is to return [DTO's](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/) instead of Entities, fetch for each the max 10 reminders in your DataTransformer and put those into the DTO. For feching you need [ManagerRegistry injected](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service).